# Easiest way to get time in hour and minutes from a long time format in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get only hour and minutes (hh:mm) from a long time format (hh:mm:ss) in sql.

Answer (score 3):

```
CONVERT(char(5), SomeDateTimeValue, 108)
```

See [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: I have tried this : "select CONVERT(char(5), '2014-01-28 23:07:06.000', 108)", and got "2014-"!!

Comment: @AfshinMoazami: because you are converting a string, not a datetime value. This works... `select CONVERT(char(5), CAST('2014-01-28 23:07:06.000' AS datetime), 108)` or `select CONVERT(char(5),GETDATE(), 108)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have time in TIME format in MySQL you can use `SELECT TIME_FORMAT (time_column,"%H:%i") from table;`
Refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @BobVale wouldn't it be good idea to specify this *important* information in the question subject or at least in text?

Comment: Possibly, but the question is tagged as sql-server

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you'd use this:

```
select time_format('12:34:44','%H:%i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEPART transact sql function [Datepart in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

You can check out the various combinations to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying representation is a DATETIME, then you can try this (mocked up with a call to `GETDATE()`).

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) AS MyHours, 
       DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) AS MyMinutes
```

Comment: What if the time is 12:01 and I don't want to show it as 12:1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is called timeCol, this will work:

```
select  RIGHT('00' + cast (DATEPART(hour,timeCol) as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('00' + cast (DATEPART(minute,timeCol) as varchar(2)), 2),
from ...
```

The DATEPART calls get you the hour & minute, the RIGHT pads with a leading zero if the value is only one digit.

Answer (score 0):

This works good for me:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( convert(varchar, YourColumnName ,108),1,5) as 'StartDate'
FROM YourTableName
```